# Почему не работает клавиша W в терминале ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура

Почему не работает клавиша `W` в терминале *ubuntu*? Вне терминала работает.

Вывод программы `ps`:

```
$ ps
 6389 pts/18   00:00:00 bash
 6608 pts/18   00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: Ctrl случайно не зажат? Выберите терминал, попрыгайте по Ctrl и проверьте ещё раз.

Comment: не зажат. Сделал так как вы сказали. Ничего. С шифтом работает.

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что значит «не работает». приведите пример ваших действий, по которому можно воспроизвести ситуацию.

Comment: Нажимаю w она не печатается в терминале, нажимаю Shift+w, печатается большая буква W.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, уточните ещё, пожалуйста: 1. что именно вы подразумеваете под «терминалом»? графический эмулятор виртуального терминала? тогда сообщиет его название — в меню обычно должен быть пункт «help → about». 2. никаких программ вы при этом не запускаете? присутствует просто приглашение командной строки? тогда выполните, пожалуйста, команду `ps` и её вывод добавьте к вопросу, нажав [edit]. 3. скопировать и вставить в «терминал» букву `w` (или текст с ней) получается?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, чтобы тот, к кому вы обращаетесь, получал уведомления, надо упоминать его явно. вот так примерно: `@alexanderbarakin`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin,. A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop. Cкопировать в терминал букву w получается.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26146/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-vkovalchuk88).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если в качестве эмулятора терминала вы используете *gnome-terminal*, то сто́ит убедиться в том, что для этой клавиши не назначен (по ошибке или недосмотру) какой-нибудь *shortcut*.

меню `edit → preferences → shortcuts`.